# Obtaining access token error 401 in Twython

Tags: python, django, twython

I am trying to veify Twitter account of user via Twython

```
def twitter_view(request):
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
auth = twitter.get_authentication_tokens(callback_url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm/', force_login=True)

request.session['oauth_token'] = auth['oauth_token']
request.session['oauth_token_secret'] = auth['oauth_token_secret']
return HttpResponseRedirect(auth['auth_url'])


def redirect_view(request):
oauth_verifier = request.GET['oauth_verifier']
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
final_step = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(oauth_verifier)
request.user.twitter_oauth_token = final_step['oauth_token']
request.user.twitter_oauth_token_secret = final_step['oauth_token_secret']
request.user.save()

return redirect('twitterapp:homepage')
```

I am getting

> Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Invalid / expired Token

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
>   "/Users/bharatagarwal/my-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 149, in get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/Users/bharatagarwal/my-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 147, in get_response  response = wrapped_callback(request,
>   *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/bharatagarwal/projects/twitterproject/mysite/twitterapp/views.py",
>   line 100, in redirect_view
>         final_step = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(str(oauth_verifier))
>
> File
>   "/Users/bharatagarwal/my-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twython/api.py",
>   line 379, in get_authorized_tokens
>       ken'), error_code=response.status_code)
>
> TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Invalid /
>   expired To             ken

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication with twython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866323/authentication-with-twython)

Comment: I have tried already seen that post but still facing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second Twython instantiation, you have to include the OAUTH_TOKEN and the OAUTH_SECRET_TOKEN obtained in the first step.

```
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

It is returning Invalid Token because the instantiation you're using didn't include the tokens you received.